# Why is a calendar entry made for each call?

Tags: s-calendar

I use a Samsung Galaxy Note.  I am noticing that each time I make, receive or miss a call, an entry is made in My Calendar, with the details of the call, incoming or outgoing, phone number etc.  Every call made / received in the phone log has one calendar entry, making the calendar totally unusable.

I am not able to find which application is doing this.  Is there any way I can stop this entry from being made for each call?

Alternatively, how do I identify which application is making this entry, by looking at the calendar entry?

Comment: I don't use Galaxy Note, so this is just a hint, not a solution: I somewhat believe that this is not from Galaxy Note. Also, there are apps (e.g. [Call Log Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.joao.android.CallLogCalendar)) that can create a calendar entry for every call. You may need to inspect each installed apps more carefully.

Comment: Hi Andrew.  Thanks for the direction... that is what I am doing for the past 2 days.  To nail the culprit.  No luck till now.  Any way to reverse the check?  How to say which app created the calendar entry by looking at the entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app SMS Backup+ has this functionality, where call log entries can be added automatically to a Google Calendar. The source code for SMS Backup+ is freely available on Github, so it may have been cloned and installed under a different name on your device.

Also if you go to your Google Account Permissions, you can see which apps have been authorized to access your Google calendars.

Comment: Well, what can I say... B.U.L.L.S...E.Y.E.!!!  It was SMS Backup+ indeed!  I have now turned off the call-log-sync-into-Calendar.  Many thanks, mlgoth!  Both your tips were very useful!